# How to use Keras Sequential with LocallyConnected layers

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, error-handling

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lg74.png)

I am trying to use locally connected neural networks to estimate finite elements of a mathematical function, using the Keras Sequential model. When I use dense layers all through, my code works perfectly and very accurately.

But when I switch to use the LocallyConnected1D layers it brings the error shown in the picture. Yet, I expect it to be working fine for any type of layers I use, even dropout ones.

So by the screenshot, I think the issue is with the dimensions, but I can't make sense of it. Any advice on what the error means in simple terms and possibly how to resolve the issue? Thanks.

The code is:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import Dense, LocallyConnected1D
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import sys
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
# %%
def LinearSampler(x_i_minus_1, x_i_plus_1, N):
    gamma=1/2;
    
    N0=int(N*gamma); Nrest=N-N0;
    p1 = x_i_minus_1 / (x_i_minus_1 + 1 - x_i_plus_1)
    p2 = (1 - x_i_minus_1) / (x_i_minus_1 + 1 - x_i_plus_1)
    x1 = np.linspace(0, x_i_minus_1, int(p1 * Nrest))
    x2 = np.linspace(x_i_minus_1, x_i_plus_1, int(N0))
    x3 = np.linspace(x_i_plus_1, 1, int(p2 * Nrest))
    x = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3))
    return x


# %% Defining the FEM tent functions

def tent_function(x, x_i_minus_1, x_i_plus_1):
    """
    Compute the tent function for a given point x and interval [x_i_minus_1, x_i, x_i_plus_1].
    k = number of finite elements, k = 1, 2, ... m < Inf
    i = index of finite element function required; 1 = 1, 2, ..., k
    """
    
    
    x_i = (x_i_minus_1 + x_i_plus_1)/2
    
    if x <= x_i_minus_1 or x >= x_i_plus_1:
        return 0
    elif x_i_minus_1 <= x < x_i:
        return (x - x_i_minus_1) / (x_i - x_i_minus_1)
    else:
        return (x_i_plus_1 - x) / (x_i_plus_1 - x_i)


# %% Basics

k = int(input('Enter the total number of finite elements: '))
i = int(input('Enter the index of the finite element to be fit: '))
if i > k:
    print("The required finite element is outside the range of the available ones. That is, 'i' MUST always be less than or equal to 'k'")
    sys.exit()
elif i == 0:
    x_i_minus_1 = 0
else:
    x_i_minus_1 = (i - 1)/(k + 1)

x_i_plus_1 = x_i_minus_1 + (2 / (k + 1)) 

# %% Generate training data set

train_x = LinearSampler(x_i_minus_1, x_i_plus_1, 50000)
train_y = np.array([tent_function(xi, x_i_minus_1, x_i_plus_1) for xi in train_x])


# %% Define the model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(64, 3, input_shape=(10, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model on some data
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=10*i) ##Early stop model in case it isn't performing
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=50, verbose=1, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

and the error is;

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 10, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='locally_connected1d_2_input'), name='locally_connected1d_2_input', description="created by layer 'locally_connected1d_2_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File e:\desktop\...\file.py:111
    history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=50, verbose=1, callbacks=[early_stop])

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70 in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filekrq21sck.py:15 in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 993, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 232, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_2" "                 f"(type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "locally_connected1d_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential_2" "                 f"(type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided indicates that there is an issue with the dimensions of the input data. The LocallyConnected1D layer expects a 3-dimensional input, but you are providing a 1-dimensional input.

To resolve this issue, you need to reshape your input data to have the correct dimensions. In your case, you can reshape your `train_x` data to have a shape of `(50000, 10, 1)`. This can be done using the `reshape` function from numpy:

```py
train_x = train_x.reshape((50000, 10, 1))
```

After reshaping the input data, you can pass it to the `model.fit` function:

```py
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=50, verbose=1, callbacks=[early_stop])
```